# "Add" button with option to add more than one item

Tags: interaction-design, buttons, interface

As part of a task in my webapp, users need to add "slots" to an object. For each slot, there's some settings that the user can adjust. Adding a slot is achieved via clicking a button.

[image]

Some users need to add a large number of slots at once, up to tens of them, all with the same settings. I'd like to add a way to create more slots at once inside the interface.

Since the vast majority of my user base are *not* going to use this feature, and they're happy with using the *Add slot* button that already exists, I'd like not to touch the existing button and leave it as it is. This is meant almost as a "power user" feature.

What's a good way of adding this feature?

One idea I had in mind was to add a small, side button like this one:

[image]

A dropdown with a number input would open, allowing the user to input the number of slots they want created. Just below that input, all inside the dropdown, there would be an *Add slots* button that allows to create that many slots.

Would this be appropriate in your opinion? Feedback as to how else I could implement this is welcome.

Comment: I think that’s a great way to solve your issue. But: Does your button move? It shouldn’t. First of all, Add buttons are typically either on top, or floating, so that they stay in place and are also visible when the list gets long. If it stays in place, simply clicking five times will add five rows, which probably would be users’ default behaviour.

Comment: It does move, yes. I reasoned if the list is long, a button on top might not be good as the user wouldn't have feedback about the fact a new slot has been created, whereas if it's at the bottom then the user immediately seen the new slot appearing.

Clicking x times on the button isn't the issue: the button "choose exercise" inside the slot comes with a lot of work to get it configured, and users sometimes want that same settings for many slots. That's when creating x slots at a time would come in handy--the app would also allow to configure them only once and apply settings to all

Comment: You could place it at the bottom, and make the footer of this list float, so that regardless of the height of the list the button is always visible (together with the control to set the random order).
Then, when the users add one or more slot items, make sure the list scroll position changes to show the users that the items have been created at the bottom. Even further, you could add a slight background highlight to the newly created items for like half a second.